# Servlet response send redirect error

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

I just get the error 404: The requested resource is not available. I can't figure out what is wrong here:

This is the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The servlet :

```
[@WebServlet(name = "controller.Servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if (LoginService.authentication(id, password)) {
            response.sendRedirect("succes.jsp");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }
        return;
    }][1]
```

The index.jsp file :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/login" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="id" >
    <br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

succes.jsp :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Succesfully</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login succesfully</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the folder structure:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGMH4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update web.xml:

```
 <servlet>
            <servlet-name>controller.Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com..Servlet(replace with your servlet class namespace)</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
```

Alternatively you can define urlPatterns in @WebServlet like this and remove servlet definition and url patterns from web.xml:

```
@WebServlet(name="controller.Servlet", urlPatterns={"/login"})
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet{
.......
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

</web-app>
```

Comment: Another problem is that he is trying to redirect to WEB-INF/succes.jsp